# Insert pop out table into excel cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible to create a pop out table/dialog in a clickable cell in Excel 2010? I would then like the sum of the table to show up in the cell.

Right now I am using a simple workaround, wherein I am entering each new number in the function bar `=0+number1+number2+etc...` but I am afraid that one day I might accidentally mess up and delete/ruin the data.

Basically this sheet is being used by multiple people to check out items from the same inventory, so I will need to apply this pop-out table to hundreds of items in a list. I am also open to other workarounds if anyone has done something similar.

EDIT: I would like each user to be able to enter each new checked out item in a separate table, with the sum of all items checked out to appear in the original cell. But there are literally thousands of items, so I also don't want thousands of new sheets either.

Answer (score 0):

All version of Excel I have come across does display the **sum** and **average** of **the selected cells** in the **Status bar**, usually found in the lower right corner of the Excel window.

It seems to me that should be exactly what you ask for.